# What is the correct punctuation of the phrase: one size fits all

Tags: idioms, punctuation, word-usage

What is the correct punctuation for the phrase: one size fits all?

I have seen two variants:

- 'one size fits all', and
- one-size-fits-all

Comment: I don't think there is a one-size-fits-all answer to this; It depends on how it's being used.

Comment: Heh, I set myself up for that one!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the phrase is used as an adjective (which it usually is), then hyphenate it:

> It is a one-size-fits-all solution.
>
> This hat is one-size-fits-all.

The phrase could be used as an independent clause, however, with "one size" being the subject:

> These hats are great. One size fits all, you know.

So in all but the last case, which I imagine is pretty rare, include the hyphens.

Comment: You beat me by two seconds!

Comment: You never know who else might be out there just itching to answer a usage question! Our answers were almost identical, too.

Comment: Yah, but you got the predicative use in, too. +1